start-stop-daemon has changed from dpkg package
I used for many years VirtualBox with both host and guest machines run Ubuntu.
Since few month I'm having hard time with Ubuntu 24.04. I'm not able anymore to reliable run a VBox machine. It hangs every 1-2 reboots during startup or even when just staring at its desktop.
I tried to create anew one from scratch at least 5 times (even with older versions of Ubuntu for guest) without luck.
When it refuses to run (i.e. see this question) I found a workaround:

reset the machine
enter in recovery mode
repair broken packages
reboot again

In this way it runs successfully, but I have to repeat this procedure every 1-2 reboots.
The vdi file is on an SSD (NTFS it that's matter, since I will need to share with a Windows installation, when it will work reliably).
So far, I tried to install debsums in order to understand what happens.
It finds only one problem:
$ sudo debsums -s 
debsums: changed file /usr/sbin/start-stop-daemon (from dpkg package)
$ sudo debsums -x dpkg
debsums: changed file /usr/sbin/start-stop-daemon (observed:2df9e20c8a09762451104025c84b7b87 expected:1fa45a74a181c6f7f26603fa1cd7265f) (from dpkg package)

Could this be the (at least one) cause of my problems?
